# Application Insights Dashboard - Set Graph Dimensions?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I am currenty setting up a new dashboard in application insights to monitor our applications in detail. To do so, I am logging custom events from my application, and using a log query, I generate a Stacked Column Chart. Like so:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYIbC.png). Notice that I am grouping on multiple dimensions, and the generated chart lets me pick which Dimension I want. (As documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/charts#multiple-dimensions)

Now, when I pin this chart to my dashboard, I lose the ability to pick the dimension I want to see there. ([Dashboard chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wskpp.png)) Is there some way to retain this, or do I have to create and pin multiple charts, one for each dimension?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Changing the dimensions of existing parts are not supported yet.
We plan to support this in the future.
I'll ask here once we add this support.